# codeigniter controller index function call requires its name

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, controller, call

I have a Controller named Categories and one function in it called index with 1 parameter $cat_id

so it looks like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class categories extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index($cat_id = null){

    }
}
```

the problem comes when i call it from the browser... i use this:

```
http://www.mysite.dev/categories/12311323
```

but returns 404 error page

instead if i use

```
http://www.mysite.dev/categories/index/12313131
```

will work fine...

how can i make sure it wont need index in the URL for the index function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default CodeIgniter routing is /controller/function/argument. In order to specify an argument, you need to first specify the function. If you want to specify an argument without the function, you need to define a custom route. Adding this line to your route configuration file should do what you want.

```
$route['categories/(:num)'] = "categories/index/$1";
```

Comment: yeah i had this but i forgot to add the /index/... damn i need some sleep

Answer (score 1):

What you describe are the default (pre-configured) routes of CI. You can define your own to make the pattern you describe in your question work. See: [URI Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)